# JSP - Loads of submit buttons and loads of IF statements

Tags: html, jsp, submit, scriptlet

My JSP page has many Submit buttons for example

```
<input type="submit" name="RemoveCustomer" value="Submit"/>
<input type="submit" name="AddCustomer" value="Submit"/>
```

and within my scriptlet tag I have something like this

```
if(request.getParameter("addByName") != null && request.getParameter("addByName").length() > 0) {
  ...
} else {
  if(request.getParameter("removeByName") != null && request.getParameter("removeByName").length() > 0) {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }

}
```

Where addByName and removeByName are HTML TextFields

Clearly I could click the button RemoveCustomer to access removeByName and do something, but if the addByName TextField was not empty it would add a customer.

What I want to know is in my scriptlet how do I know what submit button was pressed?

Comment: rule #1- DO NOT USE SCRIPTLETS! try jstl instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do request.getParameter("name of submitbutton"). Here name of submit button is RemoveCustomer or AddCustomer.

Answer (score 2):

You could put sections in `<div>` with class or id that makes clear what has happened.

It sounds to me like your JSP is in need of a good refactoring.  If you agree, I have two suggestions:

1. Eliminate all scriptlet code and use only JSTL.  JSPs are for view only; move all logic out of the page.
2. The logic really belongs in controllers on the server side.  Have a Front View Controller servlet that accepts all incoming traffic and delegates requests to classes that are written specifically to handle different use cases.
3. You might have grown to the point where your app could benefit from an MVC framework like Spring, Wicket, etc.  I'd recommend looking into one.